# Extend multiple interfaces in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I am trying to extend multiple components in LWC js.
but it is not working

I want to extend `OmniscriptBaseMixin(LightningElement)` and `NavigationMixin(LightningElement)`

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { OmniscriptBaseMixin } from 'vlocity_cmt/omniscriptBaseMixin';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class TestLWC extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(LightningElement), NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

}
```

Comment: Not tried it myself, but perhaps using ```extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(NavigationMixin(LightningElement))``` would do it?

Comment: @PhilW Yes, that'd be the appropriate syntax.

Comment: @Phil W Thanks..It works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Implementing multiple mixin classes in LWC is handled by nesting them in the extends clause. For your case simply use:

```
export default class TestLWC extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(NavigationMixin(LightningElement))
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to note that you can also use Object.assign() to extend your JS class. I think this is much cleaner and human readable. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247434/how-to-add-mixins-to-es6-javascript-classes) is an in-depth explanation.

Comment: I would not suggest using this with LWC given the way LWCs are "compiled". Using a non-standard approach is likely to trip you up.